# Is there a way to change the default photos app in Windows 10 via command line?

Tags: windows, windows-10, photos

I know that these steps will work:

> Click on Start and go to Settings > System > Default apps. Click on
> the Photo Viewer dropdown menu and select the app you'd like to use.

But other issues prevent me from using this method. Is there another way?

Comment: What is wrong with your system that you need to use a command sequence instead of doing things very simply?

Comment: Windows Start Menu does not work as per this article is a very common issue - https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/windows-10-start-menu-not-working/

Comment: You could try [SetUserFTA](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/set-default-browser-file-associations-command-line-windows-10/)

Comment: Yey! That worked! Wow. Why does MS make it so hard.

Answer (score 1):

First, you must have Admin rights to the system.

Next, you would open command prompt with Admin rights, and type this command:

```
ftype <File_Type>="<absolute_path_to_application>" "%1"
```

Make sure to replace <File_Type> with the type of file (can be found using `assoc .<File_Extention>`).  The path to the .exe MUST be absolute (meaning full path, from the C:\ drive to the file).

Credit goes to https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/file-app-association-command-prompt-windows-10/

Comment: That does not work in Windows 10. I have tried that and if i go back into Windows Explorer and double click a JPG file, it still opens in Windows Photos app, and not the app I want.

Comment: Did you replace the placeholders?  Try looking at the website that is linked in the answer.

Comment: Yes, i replaced the placeholders in angle brackets. This way of changing the default photos app does not work in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

> Windows Start Menu does not work as per this article is a very common
> issue

Try doing a Windows 10 Repair Install and fix the system.
properly.  That should also fix the App association issue as well.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to **Keep Everything**

If the Repair Install does not work, then you need to back up, check your back up and reinstall Windows fresh (User Profile damage or more serious operating system damage).

Comment: I already attempted the repair and that did not fix the issue. Gotta wonder, there must be a way to access the setting other than through the Settings UI

Comment: I amended my answer. At this point you need to reinstall Windows to get things working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to [@w32sh](https://superuser.com/users/542839/w32sh)

The solution is to use [setUserFTA](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/set-default-browser-file-associations-command-line-windows-10/).

Take that MS!